# how get next 7 day name come from timestamp

Tags: angular, timestamp

I, i would like générate table on the week the DATE for show available Appointment.
this is my component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarModel } from '../calendar-model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-semaine',
  templateUrl: './semaine.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./semaine.component.css']
})

export class SemaineComponent implements OnInit {

  startSemaine;//en timestamp

  constructor(private _calendar:CalendarModel) { 
    this.startSemaine = this._calendar.getDateMinSec(Date.now());
    this.getNameDay();
  }

  getNameDay(){
    console.log(this.startSemaine);
      //get name day 

  }

  calculNext7Day(){
    //calcul for 7 day
  }

  perHourDay(){
    //show hour journey 1H + N
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I work with timestamp, how i can get name day ? I would like show simple 7 next day in a start now day:

mardi (now is 1523994732) | mercredi | jeudi | vendrdi | samedi | dimanche | lundi

I get à timestamp now with  this.startSemaine , and I calculate next day is

next = now + 60 * 60 * 24

for start my snippet, how i cant get name day now ?
thank's for reply me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get the name of the day by this :

```
var curdate = new Date(null);
curdate.setTime(timestamp *1000);   // here timestamp  = 1523994732
var i = curdate.getDay()
var days = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat']; //name of the Days
var nameDay = days[i]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

that right, i found it:

```js
  getNameDay(){
    console.log("get next 7 day becom now");
    var curdate = new Date(null);
    curdate.setTime(1515020400*1000);   // here timestamp  = 1523994732
    var i = curdate.getDay();
    var iTemps = i;
    console.log(i+"===");
    let stop = false;
    let days = ['Lun','Mar','Mer','Jeu','Ven','Sam','Dim']; //name of the Days

    for(i;i<days.length; i++){
      console.log(days[i]);
    }
    let j=0;
    for(j;j<iTemps; j++){
      console.log(days[j]);
    }
  
  }
```